# Output nested selectors as individual lines with LESS

Tags: less

I'm just curious, if I have code written like this:

```
.newsletter-form input {
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder,
  &::-moz-placeholder,
  &:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red !important;
  }
}
```

It will output as:

```
.newsletter-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.newsletter-form input::-moz-placeholder,
.newsletter-form input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red !important;
}
```

But, I actually want it to be output as individual lines like this:

```
.newsletter-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red !important;
}
.newsletter-form input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: red !important;
}
.newsletter-form input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red !important;
}
```

How am I able to do this with LESS?

I understand I could just write it as separate lines using regular CSS, but that would be no fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I just structured it like this, without the commas, I get the desired outcome.

```
.newsletter-form input {
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red !important;
  }
  &::-moz-placeholder {
    color: red !important;
  }
  &:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red !important;
  }
}
```

Or using a mixin for flexibility.

```
.placeholder(@color) {
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: @color !important;}
  &::-moz-placeholder {color: @color !important;}
  &:-ms-input-placeholder {color: @color !important;}
}

.newsletter-form input {
  .placeholder(red)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Passing Rulesets to Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature). E.g.:

```
.newsletter-form input {
    .placeholder({
        color: red !important;
    });
}

.placeholder(@rules) {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {@rules();}
    &::-moz-placeholder          {@rules();}
    &:-ms-input-placeholder      {@rules();}
}
```

Unlike the solutions of the prev. answers, this way won't require your `placeholder` mixin to be hardcoded to a particular value or property like `color: ...` or so.

Answer (score -1):

You can create mixin that will set a color to specific selector.

Less:

```
.set-color(@selector, @color) {
  &@{selector} {
    color: @color !important;
  }
}

.newsletter-form input {
   .set-color(~"::-webkit-input-placeholder", red);
   .set-color(~"::-moz-placeholder", red);
   .set-color(~":-ms-input-placeholder", red);
}
```

Css output:

```
.newsletter-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red !important;
}
.newsletter-form input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: red !important;
}
.newsletter-form input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: To meet the OP's requirements there's no need for a `@color` variable - just use `red`